# alternative to jquery load to get only part of a page - issue with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I am using `jquery .load()` to load a div by clicking a link:

```
$('#stop_it').on('click',function(){
var chat = $("#history");
chat.load(window.location + " #history > * ");
});
```

However, if i'm inspecting the element with chrome inspector - tab "network", i see that the entire page is loaded with all the scripts inside it. You can see it on [the jquery example page](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to see what i mean. Some of these scripts in the original page are not working anymore because the scripts get duplicated.

So i'm searching for an client side alternative (if there is one) to load only the `#history` content.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the work serverside, since it needs to get the content of the page and then process it. For example only including libraries if is an ajax call. You can pass a get value if is ajax and clean up the content serverside.

Comment: No, it's not an ajax call. It's a simple click. I wanted to avoid it on server side. So there isn't any alternative, the only way to do it is on server side?

Comment: The event is a click, but jquery load is an ajax call...
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you. I thought you asked if it's inside an ajax call.